# HBASE multi node cluster setup Issue

Tags: nosql, hbase, hadoop2, master-slave

I have 3 nodes as master ,slave1,slave2 and trying to install HBASE in above cluster.

I have started HABSE in master node , but i see daemons are not running in slave nodes , do i need to issue start habse command in slave nodes as well ?

Could some body please help.

- hbase-env.sh content:

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_151/

- regionservers content:

  `slave1`
  `slave2`
  `master`
- hbase-site.xml content:

```html
<configuration>

<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://1XX.1YY.1ZZ.1WW:9000/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>master,slave1,slave2</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/hadoop/zk_data</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2222</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bashrc was pointing to another version of installed HBASE . problem solved once pointing to correct version in bashrc file. Also to clarify we have to issue start-hbase command in master node only.